# how to code to invite yahoo friends in ios7

Tags: ios7, yahoo

how to invite yahoo friends .on button click yahoo login page should be open.

afer login page oen i want send invitaion to my friend .plz suggest how can i do ?

for facebook we use following code but how we can do in yahoo.

```
-(IBAction)InviteYourFriendsBtnClk:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just smashed  friends! Can you beat it?"]
                                                title:@"StopNSwap"
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                      // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                                                      NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                                                  } else {
                                                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                          // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                                                          NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                                                      } else {

                                                          NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                                                      }
                                                  }}
                                          friendCache:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be sending an email to the person asking to follow your yahoo page.

> // From within your active view controller
>   if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
>       MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
>       mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;
>
> ```
> [mailCont setSubject:@"Follow us on Yahoo!"];
> [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"stkovf@jaydz49.com"]];
> [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Follow our apps yahoo page" isHTML:NO];
>
> [self presentModalViewController:mailCont animated:YES];
> [mailCont release]; }
> ```
>
> // Then implement the delegate method
>   - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
>   {
>       [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }

Comment: hi plz tell me how can i get yahoo friend list

Comment: Hi abhiTouchmagic try this link https://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/ I can't test it on my connection as my connection speed has been cut out but this should help

Comment: hi sir but i want open yahoo login page and then send invition to salected friend

Comment: we can send only one person .but i want to multiple person on same time

Comment: Hi abhiTouchmagic, I wouldn't have any suggestions from here on in, The only thing I would suggest to do is spend time on google(this can take hours) and find some useful code and paste it together, or you could get in touch with yahoo developers